# numeric value of the enum in select EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

model

```
public Bububu? Bububu{ get; set; } 

public enum Bububu
    {
        Bububu= 1
    }
```

controller

```
   var listOfBububu = _ecpContext.ModelBububu.Where(x => x.Login == userName )
                .Select(i => new {P = i.Bububu.Value})
                .ToList();
```

and it returns me sth like this:

> [0].Bububu = null

> [1].Bububu = null

> [2].Bububu = Bububu

What do I have to do to get me back the value according to enum? (Numerical)

to make it look like this:

> [0].Bububu = null

> [1].Bububu = null

> [2].Bububu = 1

I tried Enum.GetValue, but i don't know how to insert it

Comment: What is the type of `Bububu` property in DB?  If the table was generated automatically, it should be `int` type and return as you expect.